# crashing issue after uploading image from gallery or take photo from camera in firebase database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, react-native, react-native-firebase

photos from gallery or taking a photo from camera restarts the app without showing any error and redirecting to first page

i'm using react-native-image-picker module i tried to store image in
firebase database

> React Native version: 0.46.4 Platform: both Development Operating
>   System: MacOS, Dev tools: Android Studio navigation crash for Android

Comment: Are you sure you have CAMERA and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file?

Comment: yes i added 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Try run application from `Android Studio / Xcode` to see more informative stack trace

Comment: yes, I have already run in android studio and got error like
 "firebase crashed" Now what i have to do, how to fix this problem